# .populate on a non required field mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, database

I am trying to use populate on a non compulsory field that might have a relation with the other collection or might be blank, when I try to populate that field, it is giving error

"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id""

code:

`Paper.find(query).populate('1').populate('2').populate('3').exec(cb)`

now 3_id in paper document might be blank.

schema is like

```
var paper_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
          type:String
        },
        price: {
          type: Number
        },
        1:{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 1
           },
        2:{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 2
           },
         3:{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 3
           }
       })
```

Comment: Would you care to edit your question to include the schema definitions for the models in question?

Comment: @chridam added schema for paper

Comment: The `ref` attribute value should be a string as it tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in your case you should have defined models `1`, `2` and `3`.

Comment: It is just a abbreviation that I used, otherwise they have a string name and there are other collections with those names, But when I remove .populate('3') It works fine.

Comment: @Aditya_Anand have you found any solution